# pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame crashing on applying an operation on 10Million Records

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Configurations for loading data from PostgeSQL:

```
#Configurations
conf = (pyspark.SparkConf()
     .setMaster("local")
     .setAppName("DBs")
     .set("spark.executor.memory", "8g")
     .set("spark-driver.memory","16g"))

#Spark Context
sc=pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)

#Reading data from PostgreSQL DB Table with 10M records
sqlContext=pyspark.SQLContext(sc)
url='postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname'
properties= {'user': 'user', 'password':'pass'}
df = DataFrameReader(sqlContext).jdbc( url='jdbc:%s' % url, table='table_name', properties=properties)
```

Upon performing the operation:

```
df.head(4)
```

Getting below Error:

```
Py4JNetworkError:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:46577)
```

The traceback of the error is as follows:

```
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zaman/Downloads/Setups/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 883, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/home/zaman/Downloads/Setups/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1040, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:46577)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zaman/Downloads/Setups/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 963, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
  File "/home/zaman/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

The system status that memory is remaining constant through-out the operations as shown below:

[image: Memory is remaining 5.4 GB through-out the process.]

***Note: When I tried similar operation on same machine with same configurations but on mere 5000 records data they get executed successfully.***

Comment: Have you tried specifying `numPartitions` in your properties ? http://www.sparkexpert.com/2015/03/28/loading-database-data-into-spark-using-data-sources-api/

Comment: Since, I am using PostgreSQL source. I am unable to figure out numPartitions property in it.